# Jquery and canvas code not working on same external file

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have been mucking about with a little bit coding using jquery and canvas (not together).

I have an external javascript file and in it contains;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
/*
    NAME CHOOSER
*/
var carl = ['Sha', 'Shads', 'Cai', 'Moon', 'Sun', 'Staffy',];
var rosie = ['Mum',];
var prev;
$('button').click(function() {
    prev = $('h2').text();
    $('h2').empty().text(carl[Math.floor(Math.random() * carl.length)] + rosie[Math.floor(Math.random() * rosie.length)]).after('<p>' + prev + '</p>');
});
});
```

I also have some inline javascript which is for the canvas element;

```
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('draw');
if(canvas.getContext) {
 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
 ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 500);
}
</script>
```

When separated by using inline javascript for the canvas and an external file for the jquery everything works fine and as expected.

When adding the inline canvas javascript to the external file the canvas element is not working but the jquery is. The javascript is loaded after the canvas element as my external javascript is linked just before the closing body tag and furthermore if I remove all jquery from the external file the canvas element begins to work again.

Why is this?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I have also now tried putting the canvas code inside jquerys document ready function and outside of it and it is still not working. I have wrapped the canvas code in an anonymous function still to no avail and have even tried selecting the canvas element with jquery itself like below;

```
var canvas = $('canvas')[0];
```

But it still doesn't want to know. Putting the canvas code before all the jquery then the canvas code executes but the jquery doesn't, I really am baffled! It doesn't bother me keeping it seperate but I would like to know why it is happening.

Thanks again.

Comment: When you inline the canvas script to the jQuery file, do you keep the canvas code inside the `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })` block? If I had to guess, you're copying the canvas script into a place that is invalid, or attempting to be called before the DOM is ready.  Are any errors showing up in the javascript console when you try to run this (combined)?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to know what environment you're trying to run this in... Chrome? Firefox? IE? Secondly (and probably not related), you realize you're adding empty objects to your arrays by ending them with a comma but no object, right? (ie. `var rosie = ['Mum',];`

Comment: Thanks for the array tip I am too used to php! In chrome fully updated, I am getting a DOM exception 12 in javascript console.

Comment: @ShaShads what exception you got?

Comment: Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12, you can check the code at griffstudios.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple problems could be noted if you use the Browser Console. That's it! You can open the console pressing `Ctrl+Shift+J`:

#### In home page:

Error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` 
Solution: Link jQuery in your source

#### In namechooser page:

Error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null`

The problem:

You are trying to manipulate a div as it was a canvas, and you can't get the context of a `div` element. So this is your HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
   <h1>PORTFOLIO PROJECT <a href="/">:)</a></h1>
   <button>Click here to generate a company name!</button>
</div>
```

Solution:

Change `<div>` for `<canvas>`

#### How to avoid future problems like this?

Use the browser console, that's it!

Comment: Thank you you have helped alot :)

Comment: @ShaShads You're welcome... just use the console for this kind of stuff, you can [do a lot](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) with Chrome Developer Tools.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if I combine the code you have, above, it should look something like this: (see my jsFiddle for full context : http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/TqamB/ )

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    /*
    NAME CHOOSER
*/
    var carl = ['Sha', 'Shads', 'Cai', 'Moon', 'Sun', 'Staffy'];
    var rosie = ['Mum'];
    var prev;
    $('button').click(function () {
        prev = $('h2').text();
        $('h2').empty().text(carl[Math.floor(Math.random() * carl.length)] + rosie[Math.floor(Math.random() * rosie.length)]).after('<p>' + prev + '</p>');
    });

    var canvas = document.getElementById('draw');
    if(canvas.getContext) {
     var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
     ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
     ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 500);
    }
});
```

And, running within the context of jsFiddle, this works perfectly.

So, either you're not combining the two scripts properly (putting the canvas outside the document-ready block, for example, or somehow missing a closing brace), or there's something else amiss in your script file or markup.

Comment: I just copied the code you posted and replaced mine and it still doesn't work, the version of my chrome is `Version 24.0.1312.57 m`, what I don't get though is I can see it running perfectly from your jsfiddle in chrome, it gets weirder!

Comment: Sorry... I really need more context. Can I look at your markup somewhere?

Comment: griffstudios.com, if you load it in chrome you will see the canvas element not working but the jquery is (there is actually two pages the link is the smiley face) and thanks again

Comment: @ShaShads: if you press **Ctrl+Shift+J**, you can see that `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` at line 1. Why? You are not linking jQuery ;)

Comment: I feel dumb! Half an hour this had me stumped, oh well the best lessons are the ones worst learnt, thanks again.

Comment: @ShaShads: Check my answer, you have another problem